Multi-signature scheme with support for aggregating signatures of multiple data
If a piece of data belongs to more than one person, we can use a multisignature to sign the data and generate a signature. There are two pieces of data, $\mathrm{data}_1$ and $\mathrm{data}_2$, and four users, $a,b,c,d$, and their private keys are $\mathrm{sk}_a$,$\mathrm{sk}_b$,$\mathrm{sk}_c$,$\mathrm{sk}_d$. Suppose $\mathrm{data}_1$ belongs to user $a$ and user $b$, and these two users generate signatures $s_{1a}$ and $s_{1b}$ for it. The two signatures are aggregated to obtain the complete signature $s_1$ of $\mathrm{data}_1$. $\mathrm{data}_2$ belongs to user $a$, user $c$ and user $d$, and these three users generate signatures $s_{2a},s_{2c}$ and $s_{2d}$ for it, and aggregate the three signatures to obtain the complete signature $s_2$ of $\mathrm{data}_2$. What multi-signature method can reaggregate the signatures $s_1$ and $s_2$?
BLS multisignature has been tried, which can generate signatures $s_1$ and $s_2$, but cannot aggregate signatures $s_1$ and $s_2$.
In the signature algorithm I need, I want it to be able to perform multiple aggregations, first when multiple users have signed the same data, and second when they have generated complete signatures for different data.

OK, so the desired verification algorithm receives messages $\mathrm{data}_1$ and $\mathrm{data}_2$, and the aggregated signature; it outputs true when both messages are genuine.

Yes, that's what it means.
